# Can you make a Live DVD Persistent?

Tags: livedvd, persistence

Can you install ubuntu on to a dvd and then somehow turn persistence on? I know there is a way to turn persistence on for thumb drives (I'm out of them at the moment), but what about dvds? I just want to know if its possible to save files on a live dvd and still have them on when you boot again. If it's impossible then thats fine, i'll be getting some thumb drives pretty soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to make a LiveDVD on its own persistent without a USB to hold the persistence, and I also believe that the reason you can't comes down to the medium and why you can't sanely/safely write/erase/rewrite on CDs/DVDs so much compared to SSD/HDD/USB drives.

USB sticks are inherently reusable.  That is to say, data is written, erased, and rewritten on the drive until the memory chips wear out (there is a point where the equipment does just wear out and stop working either due to hardware fatigue and the chips stop working, or part breakage at the USB connector, or any other problem)

DVDs are different.  Data is written to the disk by lasers and physically carved into the metal layer of the disk.  Persistence would need to be able to write to the disk, erase from the disk, and rewrite, which is only able to be one on DVD-RW, and even then it can only be done so many times (far less than USB) before the disk is no longer usable.  To do persistence you would need a USB to still hold the persistence.

Also, given the difference in read/write IO speed between DVD and USB (substantially different!) you may prefer to just use a LiveUSB to expedite boot, read/write, and execution times.

Answer (score 1):

In a short answer, yes, it can be done, but it has to be done with a USB for the persistence.  The LiveCD can still be used with it just fine.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

DVD/RW discs require to be over-written each time they are written to as the table of contents has to be recreated each and every time.  Thus, they would not be a good choice for a persistent LiveCD.

Comment: Yes, but what about a multi-session disc?